# Creating a ValidIndexCollection protocol in Swift 3

Tags: swift, protocols, swift3, swift-protocols

A while ago, I made a Binary Search Tree type in Swift that I wanted to conform to the `Collection` protocol. However, the `endIndex` requirement is a "past the end" index which isn't really appropriate for a tree because each index should hold a reference to its corresponding node for O(1) access. I ended up with an optional reference (being `nil` in the case of `endIndex`), but it involved a lot of boilerplate code that I'd rather avoid.

I decided to make a `ValidIndexCollection` protocol that looks like this:

```
/// A collection defined by valid indices only, rather than a
/// startIndex and a "past the end" endIndex.
protocol ValidIndexCollection: Collection {

    associatedtype ValidIndex: Comparable

    /// The first valid index if the collection is nonempty,
    /// nil otherwise.
    var firstValidIndex: ValidIndex? { get }

    /// The last valid index if the collection is nonempty,
    /// nil otherwise.
    var lastValidIndex: ValidIndex? { get }

    /// Returns the index right after the given index.
    func validIndex(after index: ValidIndex) -> ValidIndex

    /// Returns the element at the given index.
    func element(at index: ValidIndex) -> Iterator.Element

}
```

Before I can extend this protocol to satisfy the `Collection` requirements, I have to introduce an appropriate index first:

```
enum ValidIndexCollectionIndex<ValidIndex: Comparable> {
    case index(ValidIndex)
    case endIndex
}

extension ValidIndexCollectionIndex: Comparable {
    // ...
}
```

Now I can extend `ValidIndexCollection`:

```
// Implementing the Collection protocol requirements.
extension ValidIndexCollection {

    typealias _Index = ValidIndexCollectionIndex<ValidIndex>

    var startIndex: _Index {
        return firstValidIndex.flatMap { .index($0) } ?? .endIndex
    }

    var endIndex: _Index {
        return .endIndex
    }

    func index(after index: _Index) -> _Index {
        guard case .index(let validIndex) = index else { fatalError("cannot increment endIndex") }
        return .index(self.validIndex(after: validIndex))
    }

    subscript(index: _Index) -> Iterator.Element {
        guard case .index(let validIndex) = index else { fatalError("cannot subscript using endIndex") }
        return element(at: validIndex)
    }

}
```

All seems well, the compiler doesn't complain! However, I tried to implement this protocol for a custom type:

```
struct CollectionOfTwo<Element> {
    let first, second: Element
}

extension CollectionOfTwo: ValidIndexCollection {

    var firstValidIndex: Int? { return 0 }
    var lastValidIndex: Int? { return 1 }

    func validIndex(after index: Int) -> Int {
        return index + 1
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Element {
        return index == 0 ? first : second
    }

}
```

Now the compiler complains that `CollectionOfTwo` doesn't conform to `Collection`, `Sequence`, and `IndexableBase`. The error messages are very unhelpful, it's mostly messages like:

> Protocol requires nested type `SubSequence`; do you want to add it?

or

> Default type `DefaultIndices<CollectionOfTwo<Element>>` for associated type `Indices` (from protocol `Collection`) does not conform to `IndexableBase`

Is there any way to make this work? As far as I can tell, `ValidIndexCollection` satisfies the `Collection` requirements just fine.

Some things to note:

- I called the `ValidIndexCollection` protocol method
  `validIndex(after:)` that way because calling it `index(after:)`
  resulted in a segmentation fault when trying to implement this protocol. That probably has something to do with the
  `index(after:)` method from the `Collection` protocol.
- For the same reason I used `element(at:)` instead of a subscript.
- I used `typealias _Index` instead of `typealias Index` because the latter resulted in an error message saying "`Index` is ambiguous for type lookup in this context". Again, this probably has something to do with `Collection`'s `Index` associated type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `associatedtype Element` to `ValidIndexCollection` and replacing all occurrences of `Iterator.Element` by `Element` fixed it.